# Can you paraphrase the highlighted part of passage please?

Tags: meaning

> Writing to the woman who would become his third wife, Hermann Hesse
>   complained: “Life for me now holds almost no pleasures any more, in
>   fact I am living in Hell.” The event that had reduced Hesse to this
>   state of near-despair was that his wife-to-be Ninon Dolbin had moved
>   some of his books without his permission. For him this was an
>   intolerable disruption of the orderly existence he believed essential
>   to a writer who had detached himself from the world. His independence
>   required that he hold all of humankind, and even his closest
>   companion, at a rigorously policed distance. Accordingly, although the
>   two of them lived under the same roof, he communicated with Ninon
>   mainly in writing. As his latest biographer, Gunnar Decker, relates:
>   Their day-to-day communication with one another was conducted by
>   “house letters”, like in a Trappist monastery, where one has to stay
>   silent most of the time and jot down essential communications to one’s
>   fellow monks on pieces of paper. This was the way Hesse managed to
>   tolerate the presence of another person in his vicinity; he had to be
>   sure he wouldn’t suddenly be spoken to. “How was it,” Decker asks,
>   “that Hesse believed himself to be ‘living in Hell’…when he had a
>   female friend who loved him more unreservedly than any before her, and
>   who placed herself entirely at the service of his needs?” As he
>   comments: “His note sounds positively hysterical.” It is a reasonable
>   judgement. **Decker is a scrupulous biographer with an unrivalled
>   knowledge of his subject, and this is undoubtedly the definitive
>   account of Hesse’s life and work**. **It is less clear what Decker
>   finds of intrinsic interest or value in his subject**. The most
>   striking fact about Hesse is how he was embraced by the counterculture
>   in the early Sixties – a development that secured him a posthumous
>   reputation as an exponent of the hippie “drop out” philosophy and made
>   him the most widely translated 20th-century German author.

- I need to translate this passage into a different language. Can you paraphrase the highlighted part please? My interpretation is : Decker was kind of biographer who pays attention to detail and had a great knowledge of his subject (Hesse) and his work regarding Hesse is the ultimate work a biographer can do on Hesse life, and this is a clear fact, but it is less clear to us ( audience of Decker) what values he found in Hesse.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have nailed it.

I'd like to point out one missing detail though (emphasis mine):

> " Decker was kind of biographer who pays attention to detail and had a great knowledge of his subject (Hesse) and his work regarding Hesse is the ultimate work a biographer can do on Hesse life **(and also his work)**, and this is a clear fact, but it is less clear to us ( audience of Decker) what values he found in Hesse."